# Applying the same column names to multiple tibbles

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to use the `names` function to apply the same column names to multiple dataframes, all of which have the same number of columns. I can of course do this the *wrong* way by calling `names` for each dataframe, but I'd like to do it correctly. Here's the setup:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(1,2,3,4,5)
df2 <- tibble(6,7,8,9,10)
df3 <- tibble(11,12,13,14,15)
df4 <- tibble(16,17,18,19,20)

column_names <- c("Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo")
tibbles_list <- (c("df1","df2","df3","df4"))
```

The wrong way is of course:

```
names(df1) <- column_names
names(df2) <- column_names
names(df3) <- column_names
names(df4) <- column_names
```

I'd like to somehow use the list of dataframes in `tibbles_list` (through `as.name` or `rlang::syms` or similar) to apply `column_names` to all the dataframes in one line of code, perhaps using some species of `purrr`'s `map` or one of the `apply` functions in base R, but I'm completely at a loss as to how.

Comment: How come you're making a list of the names of data frames, and not just the data frames themselves? For example `tibbles_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)`

Comment: Hi camille -- no idea. I'm probably doing many things wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tibbles_list` is just a `vector` of object identifiers as strings.  With `mget`, we get the values of the objectss in a `list`, loop through the list with `map` and use `rename_all` to change the names

```
lst1 <- map(mget(tibbles_list), ~ .x %>%
                   rename_all(~ column_names))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Or use `set_names`

```
map(mget(tibbles_list), ~ .x %>% 
            set_names(column_names))
```

NOTE: It is better to keep it in a `list` and not modifying the objects in the global env

Comment: first example fails -- complains about "Object 'Alpha' of mode 'function' was not found -- but the second example works! Thanks!

Comment: @jbfink  Sorry, there should be `~`  Try now

Comment: Actually @akrun there's a remaining problem -- the tibbles aren't actually "saved" when I do the map function -- executing either of these maps, and then calling a tibble directly (e.g. just by typing "df1" in the console) shows the old column names. How can I fix that?

Comment: @jbfink   I was on a meeting.  Forgot that tibbles_list was a character vector.  Try with `list2env` updated the meeting

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll be *much* better off if you're working with a list of data frames, rather than a list of names of data frames that you need to then pull out of your environment. If you have choice over this matter, great; if not, you can copy those data frames into a single list.

The post [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) has 7 answers with a variety of ways of doing this and reasons why, including methods for if you don't have the luxury of starting from a list.

Once that's taken care of, you can set the names with the base `setNames` (or the `rlang` wrapper `set_names`, whose powers aren't really needed here), which itself is a wrapper around `names`. Use a `purrr` mapping function, or `lapply` for a base version.

```r
library(dplyr)

dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
dfs %>%
  purrr::map(~setNames(., column_names))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta  Echo
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2       3     4     5
##### cutting remaining output

lapply(dfs, function(x) setNames(x, column_names))
# same output as above
```

Since `setNames` is a wrapper around `names`:

```r
lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  names(x) <- column_names
  x
})
# same output again
```